# Fastest way to solve small homogeneous linear systems with eigen

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, eigen

I need to solve a lot of small (n=4) homogeneous linear systems of the form Ax=0 with A being a singular matrix. I'm currently using the following code:

```
void solve(const matrix_t& A, vector_t& x){
    auto svd = A.jacobiSvd(Eigen::ComputeFullU | Eigen::ComputeFullV);
    auto V = svd.matrixV();
    x = V.col( A.rows() - 1 );
    x.normalize();
}
```

Are there any faster ways to do that?

Comment: That's what I would do.  What is your service level objective?  Have you measured the performance against representative data?  How does the 90th percentile wall time compare to that SLO?

Comment: Why are you asking for U when you are only using V? Do you need to copy V?

Comment: @MarcGlisse You are right computing U isn't really usefull. I was testing a few other ways and found out, that using LU or QR decomposition is much faster. Do these have any drawbacks?

Comment: I would try `A.fullPivLu().kernel()`, SVD decomposition is a bit overkill here (if you are sure that `A` is singular). Also, if `n==4` is known at compile time, make sure that `matrix_t` is fixed-sized 4x4.

Comment: Yes I'm sure that A is singular. My idea is to use `matrix_t` as a template type so i can pass all eigen matrix types. A quick test showed that `fullPivLu` is more than 10 times faster than `jacobiSvd`, so this might be the answer.

Comment: For the record, this [doc page](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__DenseDecompositionBenchmark.html) is useful when it comes to the relative speed of matrix decompositions in Eigen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fastest way to obtain the nullspace of a general matrix with eigen is by using its LU decomposition. In praxis I'm using the Householder QR decomposition instead of LU, because it appears to be more stable when the input matrix isn't perfectly singular. QR is still alot faster than the SVD proposed in the question and gives very similiar results for my problems. A benchmark of the different eigen decompositions can be found here: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__DenseDecompositionBenchmark.html

Code for computing the nullspace with LU, QR and SVD (note: `x.normalize()` is not required but helpful to compare the solutions):

```
template<typename matrix_t, typename vector_t>
void solveNullspaceLU(const matrix_t& A, vector_t& x){
    x = A.fullPivLu().kernel();
    x.normalize();
}

template<typename matrix_t, typename vector_t>
void solveNullspaceQR(const matrix_t& A, vector_t& x){
    auto qr = A.transpose().colPivHouseholderQr();
    matrix_t Q = qr.householderQ();
    x = Q.col(A.rows() - 1);
    x.normalize();
}

template<typename matrix_t, typename vector_t>
void solveNullspaceSVD(const matrix_t& A, vector_t& x){
    x = A.jacobiSvd(Eigen::ComputeFullV).matrixV().col( A.rows() - 1 );
    x.normalize();
}
```